# Code property in javascript functions

Tags: javascript

```
function hello(){
  console.log('Goodbye');
}
```

is an object. Almost everything in js is object. We have `name` property on it and its `hello`, but what about `code` property? How can I access that? Also, do I have the code inside `{}` or the whole whats above?

Comment: where is your `name ` and `code` property?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal hello.name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code of a function is not in a publicly accessible property. It's stored in an internal `[[Code]]` property, as specified in [Creating Function Objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2).

The `toString()` method of a function will return the entire function definition as a string.

Comment: That is what I need. Thanks. Did not knew about [[Code]]. Not very occasional on the surface of the js code.

Answer (score 2):

> Also, do I have the code inside {} or the whole whats above?

For your method, use `toString`

```
hello.toString()
```

**Demo**

```js
function hello(){
  console.log('Goodbye');
}
console.log(hello.toString());
```

And if you only want to access code between `{` and `}`, then (*assuming it is not an arrow function*)

```
var code = hello.toString();
code = code.substring( code.indexOf( "{" ) + 1 ); //remove code before first {
code = code.substring( 0, code.lastIndexOf( "}" ) - 1 ); //remove code from last }
```

If it is an *arrow function*, then

```
var hello = () => console.log('Goodbye');
var code = hello.toString();
code = code.substring( code.indexOf( "=>" ) + 2 ); //get the string after =>
```

Comment: Is that the same thing as when I just do `hello` without `()` ?

Comment: @Learnonhardway Sorry I didn't get *do hello without ()*.

Comment: @Learnonhardway `console.log()` calls `toString()` internally to get the string to display.

Comment: @gurvinder372 Means, getting the code without invoking it.

Comment: @Learnonhardway you are not invoking the function, just getting its body by doing `toString`.

Comment: Well ok. I thought it had some special property, like `hello.code` that will get me the string version of function. That is why I made parallel with `hello.name` property.

Comment: You should use `lastIndexOf("}")` instead of `indexOf("}")` if there is eg. an if-clause inside the function.

Comment: @MEE Thanks, for some reason that is what I thought I had used :)